# Can I watch Gintama' (2015) if I haven't watched previous seasons?

Tags: gintama

I want to watch this new season but It will be my very first time with Gintama, so... Maybe should I start from the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there's nothing stopping you from watching the newer episodes :)

Gintama is mainly episodic (as in, not much ongoing connection from episode to episode) so it's probably okay to do so. You might miss out a few references to past episodes though.

Of course, if you want to enjoy it fully I'd recommend you start from the very beginning.

Comment: I'd start from the beginning as well, you miss out on a lot of character introductions otherwise